# Constexpr flat_multimap

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++20

## About the Reasoning

I wrote a flat_multimap because it was slightly more efficient to read/write from disk (contiguous memory block) and because it would keep the logarithmic efficiency from a tree (using binary search). I tried to keep to the `std::multimap` standard, but there were several operations from `std::vector` which I couldn't help but implement (`capacity`, `reserve`, `resize`). I figured these would make sense to implement because they made sense to have in a sized and continuous container. There were also some methods from `std::multimap` that I didn't really think made sense to implement (`emplace(Args&&...)`, `insert(node_type&&)`) because for emplace you can't really construct the element in place, you're going to have to move it around to sort it, and for insert, I wasn't really sure how I would implement it in tandem with extract.

## The Code

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename K, typename T, typename C = std::less<K>,
    class A = std::allocator<std::pair<K, T>>>
    requires std::predicate<C, K, K>
class flat_multimap {
public:
    typedef std::pair<K, T> value_type;
    typedef T mapped_type;
    typedef K key_type;
    typedef C key_compare;
    typedef std::vector<value_type, A>::size_type size_type;
    typedef std::vector<value_type, A>::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef std::vector<value_type, A>::iterator iterator;
    typedef std::vector<value_type, A>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef const value_type& const_reference;
    typedef std::allocator_traits<A>::pointer pointer;
    typedef std::allocator_traits<A>::const_pointer const_pointer;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
    typedef std::vector<value_type, A>::allocator_type allocator_type;
private:
    std::vector<value_type, A> buffer;
    C comparator;
public:
    constexpr flat_multimap() : buffer(), comparator() {
    };
    explicit constexpr flat_multimap(const A& allocator)
        : buffer(allocator), comparator() {
    };
    explicit constexpr flat_multimap(const C& comparator,
                                     const A& allocator = A())
        : buffer(allocator), comparator(comparator) {
    };
    constexpr flat_multimap(const flat_multimap& other) noexcept
        : buffer(other.buffer), comparator(other.comparator) {
    }
    constexpr flat_multimap(flat_multimap&& other) noexcept
        : buffer(std::move(other.buffer)),
        comparator(std::move(other.comparator)) {
    }
    constexpr flat_multimap& operator=(const flat_multimap& other) noexcept {
        return *this = flat_multimap(other);
    }
    constexpr flat_multimap& operator=(flat_multimap&& other) noexcept {
        std::swap(buffer, other.buffer);
        std::swap(comparator, other.comparator);
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr ~flat_multimap() {
    }
    constexpr allocator_type get_allocator() const noexcept {
        return buffer.get_allocator();
    }
    constexpr size_type size() const noexcept {
        return buffer.size();
    }
    constexpr size_type max_size() const noexcept {
        return buffer.max_size();
    }
    constexpr size_type capacity() const noexcept {
        return buffer.capacity();
    }
    constexpr void resize(size_type count) {
        buffer.resize(count);
    }
    constexpr void reserve(size_type new_cap) {
        buffer.reserve(new_cap);
    }
    constexpr void shrink_to_fit() {
        buffer.shrink_to_fit();
    }
    constexpr bool empty() const noexcept {
        return buffer.empty();
    }
    constexpr void clear() noexcept {
        buffer.clear();
    }
    constexpr pointer data() noexcept {
        return buffer.data();
    }
    constexpr const_pointer data() const noexcept {
        return buffer.data();
    }
    constexpr iterator insert(const value_type& value) {
        return buffer.insert(
            std::upper_bound(
                cbegin(), cend(), value,
                [](const value_type& left, const value_type& right) {
                    return C()(left.first, right.first);
                }),
            value);
    }
    constexpr iterator insert(value_type&& value) {
        const_iterator destination = std::upper_bound(
            cbegin(), cend(), value,
            [](const value_type& left, const value_type& right) {
                return C()(left.first, right.first);
            });
        return buffer.insert(destination, std::move(value));
    }
    constexpr size_type erase(const key_type& key) {
        const auto [first, last] = equal_range(key);
        size_type dist = std::distance(first, last);
        buffer.erase(first, last);
        return dist;
    }
    constexpr size_type count(const key_type& key) const {
        const auto [first, last] = equal_range(key);
        return std::distance(first, last);
    }
    constexpr bool contains(const key_type& key) const {
        const_iterator first = lower_bound(key);
        return (!(first == buffer.cend()) and !(comparator(key, first->first)));
    }
    constexpr std::pair<iterator, iterator> equal_range(const key_type& key) {
        return std::make_pair(lower_bound(key), upper_bound(key));
    }
    constexpr std::pair<const_iterator, const_iterator> equal_range(
        const key_type& key) const {
        return std::make_pair(lower_bound(key), upper_bound(key));
    }
    constexpr iterator lower_bound(const key_type& key) {
        return std::lower_bound(begin(), end(), key,
            [this](const value_type& left, const key_type& right) {
                return comparator(left.first, right);
            });
    }
    constexpr const_iterator lower_bound(const key_type& key) const {
        return std::lower_bound(cbegin(), cend(), key,
            [this](const value_type& left, const key_type& right) {
                return comparator(left.first, right);
            });
    }
    constexpr iterator upper_bound(const key_type& key) {
        return std::upper_bound(
            begin(), end(), key,
            [this](const key_type& left, const value_type& right) {
                return comparator(left, right.first);
            });
    }
    constexpr const_iterator upper_bound(const key_type& key) const {
        return std::upper_bound(
            cbegin(), cend(), key,
            [this](const key_type& left, const value_type& right) {
                return comparator(left, right.first);
            });
    }
    constexpr void merge(flat_multimap<K, T, C, A>& source) {
        std::vector<value_type, A> vec(size() + source.size(),
                                       buffer.get_allocator());
        std::swap(buffer, vec);
        std::merge(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), source.buffer.cbegin(),
                   source.buffer.cend(), buffer.begin(),
                   [this](const value_type& left, const value_type& right) {
                       return comparator(left.first, right.first);
                   });
        source.clear();
    }
    
    constexpr void merge(flat_multimap<K, T, C, A>&& source) {
        std::vector<value_type, A> vec(size() + source.size(),
                                       buffer.get_allocator());
        std::swap(buffer, vec);
        std::merge(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), source.buffer.cbegin(),
                   source.buffer.cend(), buffer.begin(),
                   [this](const value_type& left, const value_type& right) {
                       return comparator(left.first, right.first);
                   });
        source.clear();
    }
    constexpr iterator begin() noexcept {
        return buffer.begin();
    }
    constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept {
        return buffer.begin();
    }
    constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept {
        return buffer.cbegin();
    }
    constexpr iterator end() noexcept {
        return buffer.end();
    }
    constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept {
        return buffer.end();
    }
    constexpr const_iterator cend() const noexcept {
        return buffer.cend();
    }
    constexpr reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept {
        return buffer.rbegin();
    }
    constexpr const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept {
        return buffer.rbegin();
    }
    constexpr const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept {
        return buffer.crbegin();
    }
    constexpr reverse_iterator rend() noexcept {
        return buffer.rend();
    }
    constexpr const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept {
        return buffer.rend();
    }
    constexpr const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept {
        return buffer.crend();
    }
};
```

## Concerns & Questions

- In a lot of places, I have to compare a key of an entry to an entry, in which case I call the comparator by accessing the key of the entry. Could there be a more efficient way to do this?
- An extension of the above point, could I implement `emplace(Args&&...)` to construct the key, and use something like `std::upper_bound` to call emplace on the vector buffer with the full set of arguments?
- Do I need to implement the Rule of Five here, because I'm not actually managing any memory myself?
- Should I implement the remainder of the `std::multimap` constructors?

## Curiosities

- I noticed while implementing merge that `std::inplace_merge` isn't constexpr, so I ended up using `std::merge` instead. Does anyone know why it isn't constexpr?

Comment: Also, I was somewhat impatient for C++23, and didn't want to use `boost`, so I ended up implementing this as an exercise for my coding skills.

Comment: For caching reasons, I think the vector for the key and values should be separate.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili From my attempts to do so, it makes iterators complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Try to match `std::flat_multimap`'s interface

You already went quite far to make it look like a similar container from the standard library, but since we already know [`std::flat_multimap`](https://wg21.link/P0429R9) is going to be in C++23, it would be good if you could match its interface:

### Add `emplace()`

> There were also some methods from `std::multimap` that I didn't really think made sense to implement (`emplace(Args&&...)`, `insert(node_type&&)`) because for emplace you can't really construct the element in place, you're going to have to move it around to sort it, and for insert, I wasn't really sure how I would implement it in tandem with extract.

I would implement this even if it doesn't give you the same performance benefit it has in `std::multimap`; it still is useful to be able to forward arguments directly to the constructor instead of having the caller create a temporary object. Also, consider code that is currently using a regular `std::multimap`, and you wnat to convert it to `flat_multimap` for some reason, then it would be great if you didn't have to find and modify all existing calls to `emplace()`.

### Make the underlying container type a template parameter

It's great that you at least provided a way for the user to supply their own allocator, but even better would be to make it possible to change the underlying container type completely. For example, a [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) could be used, which is a little bit slower to access, but has stable pointers, can hold non-movable types, and has much less overhead when calling `resize()`.

`std::flat_multimap` also uses two containers: one for the keys and one for the values, which is more cache-friendly. Another benefit is that it's simpler to call the comparator.

### Handle non-`key_type` keys

Suppose `key_type` is some large struct. Normally you would only compare one `key_type` to another `key_type`. However, it's not that rare to have a type `A` that actually be compared to a type `B`. Now suppose that I want to check if there is an entry in the map whose key matches some value that has a type different than `key_type`. Because you only have one `contains()` function that only accepts a `const key_type&` parameter, the compiler now has to create a temporary `key_type` from that value. This might be expensive.

The STL containers actually have overloads (starting at least for some member functions in C++14) that take arbitrary key types, so they can pass the provided values directly to the comparator without forcing any implicit conversions. So for example, in addition to your existing `contains()` you should:

```
template <typename K>
constexpr bool contains(const K& key) const {
    const_iterator first = lower_bound(key);
    return !(first == buffer.cend()) and !(comparator(key, first->first));
}
```

The same goes for all functions that take a `key_type` parameter.

### Implement the rest of the constructors and member functions

> Should I implement the remainder of the `std::multimap` constructors?

Yes, if you want this to be a drop-in replacement you should definitely do that, and also check for other missing member functions.

## Remove or `default` the special member functions where possible

> Do I need to implement the Rule of Five here, because I'm not actually managing any memory myself?

You have implemented your own destructor and copy/move constructors/assignment operators, but they do exactly the same thing as what the compiler would generate itself. I would just remove all of them, this way you will also follow the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

## Be careful with `noexcept`

If you mark a member function `noexcept`, but something it does could actually `throw`, then instead the program will abort, with no possibility for the caller to `catch` the error. So you should only do this if you are absolutely sure nothing can throw.

Consider your copy constructor for example: it makes a copy of the underlying `std::vector`. But `std::vector`'s own copy constructor is not `noexcept`, and it's easy to see why: it will allocate memory, and memory allocation can fail with [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc).

I would remove `noexcept` from all the constructors and assignment operators. If you allow custom containers to be used, then you could consider using [`noexcept(…)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) with a parameter to pass through the `noexcept`ness of the underlying operations. Note that most containers have `noexcept` move constructors and move assignment operators, but not all of them, so it would be safe for `std::vector`, but not if you allow arbitrary underlying containers.

## Use `comparator` instead of `C()`

The comparator is an object that might have state. So you should always use the `comparator` function instead of creating a default-constructed temporary `C()` like you did in `insert()`.

If you don't see why, consider:

```
template<typename K>
struct AscOrDescComparator {
    bool descending{};

    bool operator<(const K& lhs, const K& rhs) {
        if (descending)
            return lhs > rhs;
        else
            return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

auto map = flat_multimap<int, int>(AscOrDescComparator<int>{true});

map.insert(…); // uses C(), which is ascending
map.count(…); // uses comparator, which is descending
```

## About `std::inplace_merge`

> I noticed while implementing merge that `std::inplace_merge` isn't constexpr, so I ended up using std::merge instead. Does anyone know why it isn't constexpr?

The problem is that `std::inplace_merge` [allocates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge#Notes) a temporary buffer. Since C++20 you can use `new` in limit ways in `constexpr` contexts, and I would assume that the temporary buffer would be compatible with that. If there is no other reason why it couldn't be possible, then it might just be that the C++ standards committee hasn't come around to declare this `constexpr` yet.

## Prefer `using` instead of `typedef`

This is just a minor issue, but I recommend you use `using` decalarations instead of `typedef`s. `using` more clearly separates the type from the name, which is especially important if you want to create aliases for arrays and function pointers.

Comment: I believe the move constructor and move assignment are correctly `noexcept`. They can be implemented with `std::swap`, which is `constexpr` and `noexcept` in C++20. The default constructor also only needs the default constructor of `std::vector`, which is `constexpr` and `noexcept`.

Comment: Oops! I missed a few `C()` when I switched over to `comparator`. My bad!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a STL way to implement the zipped iterator required for the iterators with 2 separate containers.

Comment: Typedef vs using is a minor issue, but it was the first thing that tripped me. Using is so much easier to read IMO.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Wait until you `typedef` a function pointer.

Comment: @Davislor I have done that many times, and hated it every time. I'm so happy with modern C++, I'm never going back to C.

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of the major compilers have implemented flat_map (or flat_multimap), presumably because of the iterator issue. One of them had implemented flat_set, because that's simple and is only a single vector.

Answer (score 4):

You’ve gotten some good advice from G. Sliepen so far.  I’d only add a few things:

### Use `default` where Appropriate

Your default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, assignment and move assignment all just default-initialize, copy or move the fields of your `class`.  If you use the `default` implementation, the compiler will do a better job of it.  In particular, it can implicitly add `constexpr` and `noexcept` if and only if the arbitrary comparator object supports them, which would otherwise be a real hassle.

### Implement `swap`

You should immediately use this everyplace that currently does multiple swaps, of the internal data and the comparator.  You’ll get several advantages right away:

- One swap of a component cannot fail after the first succeeded, leaving the object in an inconsistent state
- You can add fields, such as a top-level `allocator`, and need to change the code in only one place
- The compiler won’t ever forget about one of the fields

### Use `[[no_unique_address]]` on Your Comparator

In most use cases, the comparator will be a unit type, and this lets the compiler optimize it out.

### Consider Restricting the Auxiliary Types

In particular, the clauses:

```
requires std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<C> &&
         std::is_nothrow_swappable<C>
```

would make it safe to declare your default constructor, move constructor, move assignment, swap and anything else that you can implement from them as `noexcept`.

It is extremely unlikely that you will ever actually need a comparator class whose default constructor and swap operation could `throw`.  (Maybe you’re dynamically allocating a random permutation as the ordering for each instance?)  If you ever actually do, you probably just want to remove the affected `noexcept` clauses.  However, an alternative if you actually want to keep them where possible would be to declare a second template overload, identical but for removing `noexcept`, and restricting it to

```
requires !std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<C> ||
         !std::is_nothrow_swappable<C>
```

### Consider Allocator and Comparator Concepts

If you define a `concept` for an allocator of T and one for a comparator over T, the compiler can check the requirements immediately at compile time and give a useful error message, instead of crashing somewhere in the middle of an instantiation, in a way that will make no sense to someone who didn’t realize that the type parameter needed to be a comparator.

```cpp
/* Matches the interface of an allocator, such as std::allocate<T>.
 */
template<class A, typename T>
concept allocator = requires(A a, std::size_t n) {
    {a.allocate(n)} -> std::same_as<T*>;
    {a.deallocate(a.allocate(n), n)} -> std::same_as<void>;
};

/* Matches the interface of a comparator for T, such as std::less<T>
 */
template<class C, typename T>
concept comparator = requires(T x, C c) {
    {c(x,x)} -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
};
```

lets you write

```cpp
requires allocator<A, K> &&
         comparator<C, K>
```